# If f is a continuous function then is the derivative bounded?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, numerical-methods, uniform-continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I was reading book by John Matthews on Numerical Analysis wherein I was going through the proof of Fixed Point Theorem. In its hypothesis it assumes that f, f' belong to C[a,b], K is a positive constant, f(x) belongs to [a,b] for all x in [a,b] and if |f'(x)|<=K<1 for all x in [a,b] then the iteration function will converge to a fixed point p in [a,b].

Before the proof begins there is a remark which says "Because f is continuous on an interval containing p, it is permissible to use the simpler criterion |f'(x)|<=K<1."

What I don't understand is how can we say that the derivative is bounded and that too specifically less than 1.

All I could think of was Lipschitz criterion which says |f(y)-f(x)| < M|y-x|, which implies |f'(x)|< M. Since the domain of f is closed and bounded, f is uniformly continuous. But that does not imply Lipschitz continuity, right?

I am stumped by the assumption that the derivative is bounded. Any help will be of great use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You say that one of the hypotheses is that $f'$ is bounded, and then you ask why we can assume that $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: What I mean to ask is whether the assumption of derivative being bounded valid or not? @Bungo

Comment: If it's given as a hypothesis, of course it's a valid assumption, provided it doesn't contradict any of the other hypotheses.

Comment: To answer the question in the subject line, "if $f$ is a continuous function then is the derivative bounded?" The answer to this is no, not necessarily. For example, let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. The derivative is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ for $x > 0$, and the one-sided derivative at $x=0$ is $+\infty$. Moreover, in general a continuous function need not be differentiable everywhere, or even anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

We have the hypothesis that $|f'(x)| \le K <1$ for all $x \in [a,b].$ By the mean value theorem we get

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le K|x-y|$$

for all $x \in [a,b].$